# Changing comment in Putty .ppk file stop it accepting password

Tags: ssh, putty

I wanted my putty key to have a more descriptive comment rather than just the date so I opened it up in text editor and changed it.  After I did pageant wouldn't accept the password anymore.

Luckily I had it backed up.  How do I change the comment without breaking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need to use puttygen to do this.

Run puttygen and load the .ppk file

[image: Key wit date comment]

Then change the comment by editing the key comment field

[image: updated key comment]

Save the private key and load it into pageant

[image: pageant view]